# How to move SharePoint Provider Hosted App from development environment to production environment?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, provider-hosted-app, sql-server-2012

I'm using SharePoint server 2013 along with SQL server 2012, I have developed a provider hosted app in my development environment. Can anybody tell me how to move my app from development to production environment.

Answer (score 1):

Hello in this link is described how to deploy Provided Hosted Apps
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/russmax/2014/06/26/part-2-intro-to-provider-hosted-apps-develop-package-and-deploy/ .

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

First of all install and configure your Production environment for SharePoint apps.

Then follow below steps:

- Open `http://<SharePoint-Production site>/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx`.
- Generate client ID and client secret from production site.
- Open source code in Visual Studio -> add this Client ID, Client Secret and other required details in Web project's web.config file and App project's appmanifest file.
- Publish app and web project from source code.
- Upload app file in production site's app catalog site. And host published web files in Production server's IIS or any other dedicated server.